# Excel data into html output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have managed to find out how to pull data from a excel file into HTML.

I am now trying to look how to search for values within a set of cells. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if my answer is not helpful, i think i will need some more info, an example of what you are trying to search for/against and what you are looking to do with the results.

Comment: Please provide code how you were able to convert the Excel data to HTML. That will help to answer how to search in the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <script>
        function mytest1() {
            var Excel, Book; // Declare the variables
            Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); // Create the Excel application object.
            Excel.Visible = false; // Make Excel invisible.
            Book = Excel.Workbooks.Add() // Create a new work book.
            Book.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = document.all.my_textarea1.value;
            Book.SaveAs("C:/temp/TEST.xls");
            Excel.Quit(); // Close Excel with the Quit method on the Application object.
        }

        function mytest2() {
            var Excel;
            Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
            Excel.Visible = false;
            form1.my_textarea2.value = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/temp/TEST.xls").ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value;
            Excel.Quit();
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <form name="form1">
            <input type=button onClick="mytest1();" value="Send Excel Data">
            <input type=text name="my_textarea1" size=70 value="enter ur data here">
            <br><br>
            <input type=button onClick="mytest2();" value="Get Excel Data">
            <input type=text name="my_textarea2" size=70 value="no data collected yet">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wouldn't this only work in IE unless the user jumps through some hoops to install active x on the other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is likely going to help you with that. when building the HTML i would also add data-[somethingHelpfulWhenSearching] or add class values that could help.

then you can search for the item by class

```
$('.[searchableClassName]')
```

or by data attribute:

```
$('[data-[somethingHelpfulWhenSearching]') //only looking that the tag exists
$('[data-[somethingHelpfulWhenSearching]="something im looking for"') //only looking that the tag and checking the value
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

From the way you worded the question, it sounds like you have a table in your HTML, and you just want to loop over all of the cells to check which cells contain a given value, and return those DOM nodes that contain the provided search string within their text content. If that's an accurate interpretation, here is a Vanilla JS solution:

```
function findCells(str) {
    var allCells = document.querySelectorAll("td");
    var matchingCells = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < allCells.length; i++) {
        if (allCells[i].textContent.indexOf(str) !== -1) {
            matchingCells.push(allCells[i]);
        }
    }
    return matchingCells;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery, try [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), which is a jQuery plugin and does a lot more than filtering for you. It allows for both client side and server side filtering, so it's not a problem if your table is large.